# Resized partition doesn't get mounted

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

After I cloned my HDD to my external hard drive (EHD?) using MiniTool Partition Wizard, I was not able to access it, only from Command Prompt with admin rights.
After trying everything I decided for whatever reason to resize my external hard drive (MiniTool split it in 2 partitions, 1 unused, and I merged them), also using MiniTool Partition Wizard.

But now I'm not able to see the drive's contents at all. Instead it says E:\ is unavailable. I'm still able to see the drive in Minitool Partition Wizard and in Disk Management, but I'm not able to do anything in the second tool.

Is there any way I can mount my EHD again? I'm fine if I have to start over. If so, what do you recommend I do different next time?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a drive letter to it?

Comment: I was not able to do this using Disk Management, but I havve now fixed it with Minitool Partition. Perhaps a command could've fixed this as well? It would be a nice extension to my answer for those who don't have the software.

Answer (score 1):

Using Minitool Partition Wizard I was able to mount the partition to a new letter.

1. Right click on partition.
2. Change letter.

I'm using version 10.2.3

I still have the access denied problem, but I will create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, posting screenshots is much useful to analyze the issue. You may try using the Check File System feature or contact minitool's support center.